# PHP file_get_contents and others return 404 but URL is accessible via browser

Tags: php, web-scraping, phantomjs, command-line-interface

I'm trying to make a PHP CLI application that scrapes an array of URLs that are direct links to an image like:

https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6f6e33_4e2920af05b4440f87880154b5cfcc80~mv2_d_1500_1500_s_2.png

While you can see that the URL is publicly accessible, it seems that no matter what I try to recover it and add it to my local machine I get 404. I have checked to make sure that allow_url_fopen is set to On in my php.ini, I tried ignoring the 404 and still attempted to return a result (CURL, file_get_contents), spoofing my user-agent and I have tried file_get_contents(), copy(), curl, and a couple other methods and got the same result; the 404.

This is what the functions in question look like:

**Function that takes array of file paths and feeds it to download function.**

```
     /**
     * @param array $locations
     * Downloads images at the specified locations into the directory specified in the constructor. 
     */
    public function scrapeImages($locations){
        echo "Attempting to download images from given source data. Standby... \n";
        foreach($locations as $location){
            echo "Scraping: ".$location;
            $fname = basename($location);
            //$this->downloadFile($location, $this->formatDirectory($this->dir).$fname);
            file_put_contents($this->formatDirectory($this->dir).$fname,$this->downloadFile($location));
        }
    }
```

**Function that actually does the downloading.**

```
     /**
     * @param string $path 
     * Checks to see if a file exists and is readable then if it is, downloads it. 
     */
    public function downloadFile($path){
        if(!file_exists($path)){
            echo "File does not exist! \n";
        }
        if(!is_readable($path)){
            echo "File is not readable! \n";
        };
        return file_get_contents(trim($path));
    }
```

The entire codebase of this can be found here if you need to analyize futher --
https://github.com/ErvinSabic/SabicRipper

I did a few hours of searching the web and eventually gave up. So I figured I'd post here. Any suggestions?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: to my knowledge file_get_contents() method accepts relative path. are you providing full path of the file?

Comment: What happens if you run this (on the same server) in a new php file?
`<?php
$image = 'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6f6e33_4e2920af05b4440f87880154b5cfcc80~mv2_d_1500_1500_s_2.png';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

$src = 'data: image/png;base64,'.$imageData;
echo '<img src="' . $src . '">';
?>`
Works perfectly fine here. So I have no reason to think that the server is actively blocking your request.

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($path)` to the top of `downloadFile()` and report its value back here? I suspect there's something wrong with the url, causing a 404 because you're accessing a file/url that actually doesn't exist.

Comment: @Nielles - That given script displays the image as I would expect.

Comment: Also dumping the path returns the exact same path that I gave it originally because I was able to copy it and paste it into a browser and access the resource.

Comment: If all else fails I can just do shell_exec("wget ".$path);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was using wget since most other methods were not working. Below is the working function.

```
     /**
     * @param string $path 
     * Checks to see if a file exists and is readable then if it is, downloads it. 
     */
    public function downloadFile($path){
        echo "Grabbing File:" .$path."\n";
        shell_exec("wget -P".$this->getDirectory()." ".$path);
        //echo "Attempting to place ".basename($path)." in ".$this->getDirectory();
    }
```

I never really found out why it would return a 404 to a publically accessible URL. But that was the work around I came up with. You can view the whole file [here.](https://github.com/ErvinSabic/SabicRipper/blob/master/sabicripper.php)